# Share Navigation Options for Multiple Stack Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Using react native with react navigation I use a DrawNavigator and several StackNavigators. Now I want to define the header style (header comes with StackNavigator) of the StackNavigator just once and for all StackNavigators.

This is what i have:

```
// View1.js

export default StackNav1 = createStackNavigator(
    {
        View1: View1Screen,
        View2: View2Screen
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#9eb9b3',
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                },
                headerLeft: (
                    <Icon style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }} name="bars" size={30}
                        onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
                    />
                ),
            }
        }
    }
)

// View2.js

export default StackNav2 = createStackNavigator(
    {
        View3: View3Screen,
        View4: View4Screen
    },
    // here I need to define the style from View1.js again ?!
)
```

Is there a smarter solution to share the appearance than writing it over and over again.

When the app is scaling I probably will have a lot StackNavigators and want them to have the same header/appearance.

I appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `stackNavigatorConfig` which is the second parameter of react navigation methods.

```
stackNavigatorConfig = {
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#9eb9b3'
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold'
      },
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon
          style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
          name="bars"
          size={30}
          onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}
        />
      )
    };
  }
};
```

Then you can use it like

```
export default StackNav1 = createStackNavigator({
      View1: View1Screen,
      View2: View2Screen
  },
  stackNavigatorConfig);

export default StackNav2 = createStackNavigator({
    View3: View3Screen,
    View4: View4Screen
  },
  stackNavigatorConfig);
```

Comment: works just fine, don't know what I have done wrong, always had problems to access the navigation props when I wanted to outsource that definition